# Accessing element in deep Json object where keys are dynamic in C#

Tags: json, json.net

I am currently working on JSON data from a graph database where the keys are dynamic in nature

```
"A": {
  "key": {
    "id": "A",
  },
  "value": {
    "B": {
       "key": {
         "id": "B",
       },
       "value": {
         "D": {
           "key": {
             "id": "D",
           },
         "value": {},
    "C":{
       "key": {
         "id": "C",
        },
       "value": {}
 }
```

Where key stores the node information and values store the child information.

Here A is the root node and B and C are its child node. Similarly for B, D is the child node. Is there any way that for every parent node I can get the id of its child node E.g For A(which is known to me) I want to its child nodes' id i.e B and C.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Sure you can if you design or select appropriate data models.  What are you using now?  Are you loading into a `JToken` or are you deserializing to some set of POCOs?  If the latter can you share what you have so far?

Comment: I am using JToken as of now..but if you can help me with some link for the latter, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your JSON as you have it in your question is not valid.  There are missing braces and extra commas.  If I go by your description, I think it should be like this:

```
{
  "A": {
    "key": {
      "id": "A"
    },
    "value": {
      "B": {
        "key": {
          "id": "B"
        },
        "value": {
          "D": {
            "key": {
              "id": "D"
            },
            "value": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "C": {
        "key": {
          "id": "C"
        },
        "value": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can model this structure with the following classes:

```
class Node
{
    public Key Key { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Node> Value { get; set; }
}

class Key
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize the JSON like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Node>>(json);
```

To get a list of the child IDs for a given node, you can add a short helper method to the `Node` class:

```
public List<string> GetChildIds()
{
    return Value.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.Key.Id).ToList();
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Node a = result["A"];
List<string> ids = a.GetChildIds();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", ids));
```

Output:

```
B, C
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MOeA69